# AJAX Chat, refresh and a lot of messages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Im programming an ajax chat by myself at the moment. The core stuff is finished, but I got 2 problems:

1. Im checking for new messages every 2 seconds, and if there are new messages I add them with .append() to the parent chat window. But the chat flickers every time i append an element and thats neither good looking nor an acceptable issue. And, wich leads me to my second problem, resets the scrolling of the element.
2. Because I want the chat to always be scrolled to the bottom, I use `.animate({ scrollTop: $(document).innerHeight() }, 1);` at the moment. But at an certain amount of messages, or child elements, the scroll just stays halfway trough...

I looked up both problems but haven't found any help yet. And since I did the whole chat by myself I googled a lot.

Thanks for any suggestions or help, how to improve the chat! :)

EDIT: The append code

```
        `// For loop for every chat window
        for(i = 0; i < chatListArray.length; i++)
        {
            (function(id) {
                // Ajax call to get the chat history
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'code/submit/submitGetChat.php',
                    data: "id=" + id,
                    success: function(data){              
                        $('#chatItemContent_' + id).empty(); // Clear the window
                        $('#chatItemContent_' + id).append(data); // Append the new chat history
                        $('#chatItemContent_' + id).animate({ scrollTop: $(document).innerHeight() }, 1); // scroll down to bottom, to display the latest messages
                    }
                });
            })(chatListArray[i]); // callback
        }`
```

Comment: Please show that append code. Probably you try to append messages in a loop with many append calls. Try to concatenate them before appending and having them display:none style (or some class with that style like .hidden) which you will remove after append.

Comment: why are you clearing the element?

Comment: How would you do it? Just respond with NEW messages to the ajax call and just append them?

Comment: Why do you clear before every append? Probably should not do that - submitGetChat should send back only new messages. You can send ID of last message or timestamp so it would know which ones it should send back.

Answer (score 0):

When you scrolling you are getting the height of the document, not the element which you want to scroll. Have you tried this?

```
$('#chatItemContent_' + id).animate({ scrollTop: $('#chatItemContent_' + id).innerHeight() }, 1);
```

It will set scrollTop according to current chat window height, not the document height.

Comment: I limited the amount of messages to 20 but this bug still apears, even with a few messages..